# Lambda Works on Latest Visual Studio, but Doesn't Work Elsewhere

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, lambda, compiler-bug

So I've written a nasty lambda to [satisfy a "shortest amount of code necessary to achieve this" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41101145/2642059):

```
values.resize(distance(
    begin(values),
    remove_if(begin(values), end(values),
        [i = 0U, it = cbegin(intervals), end = cend(intervals)](const auto&) mutable {
        return it != end && ++i > it->first && (i <= it->second || (++it, true));
    })
));
```

My problem is that on Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 version 14.0.25425.01 this outputs the desired:

> 4.2 9.1 2.3 0.6 6.4 3.6 1.4 7.5

But on [all the other compilers I've tried](http://ideone.com/UOhuvO) I get:

> 4.2 2.3 0.6 1.2 0.3 1.4 2.5 7.5

Can anyone tell me what's causing the different behavior?

Comment: What is `(++it, true)` doing? Never seen this before.

Comment: @Havenard increments `it`, evaluates as true

Comment: I believe clang since version 3.4 produces your desired output too: [see here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ia69zQqk3HmuEMCf)

Comment: @Havenard That's the comma operator: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

Comment: @W.F. Great observation. I know this was *just* fixed in Visual Studio, cause if I try to run this same code [on Update 1](http://rextester.com/QMEU55701) I get the wrong answer.

Comment: You've got undefined behaviour there ... `++i > it->first && (i ` involves using i twice, once with the pre-increment operator.

Comment: @UKMonkey You have a source for that? The left hand side of the logical-and should complete first and I would think that after that the value of `i` would be incremented.

Comment: @W.F. Something fishy is afoot. If I use clang here it doesn't work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8c6c21dcfdf5e30 An optimization problem perhaps?

Comment: @JonathanMee yes also on godbold.org clang 3.4.1 has a problem with compilation(?) PS. I think UKMonkey may be right in his diagnosis, although can't find reference right now for that...

Comment: @UKMonkey OK I got a source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/2642059 this *is* defined behavior, you're thinking of when a pre-incremented value is used in a comma separated list.

Comment: @W.F. I just found a source, that is an incorrect diagnosis. This behavior is defined (although sketchy.)

Comment: Good job finding that - knew I'd seen it somewhere... in any case, "nasty lambda" is pretty accurate ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are relying on the fact that the exact closure you pass into the algorithm is the one used as the predicate, but the standard allows it to be copied:

> `[algorithms.general]/10 (N4140)`: [Note: Unless otherwise specified, algorithms that take function objects as arguments are permitted to copy
>   those function objects freely. Programmers for whom object identity is important should consider using a
>   wrapper class that points to a noncopied implementation object such as reference_wrapper (20.9.3),
>   or some equivalent solution. —end note ]

This is exactly what libstdc++ does. From v6.2.1:

```
template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Predicate>
_ForwardIterator
__remove_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
            _Predicate __pred)
{
    __first = std::__find_if(__first, __last, __pred);
    if (__first == __last)
    return __first;
    _ForwardIterator __result = __first;
    ++__first;
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
    if (!__pred(__first))
        {
        *__result = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first);
        ++__result;
        }
    return __result;
}
```

That call to `std::__find_if` at the start of the function copies `__pred`, which means that the value of `i` is incremented a bit within `std::__find_if`, but this doesn't change what's going on at the call site.

To fix this problem, you could use `std::ref`:

```
auto clos = [i = 0U, it = cbegin(intervals), end = cend(intervals)](const auto&) mutable {
    return it != end && ++i > it->first && (i <= it->second || (++it, true));
};
values.resize(distance(begin(values), std::remove_if(begin(values), end(values), std::ref(clos))));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b102ebf777ce671)

Comment: Gah! It's `mutable`! Why in the world would libstdc++ copy it. That's the dumbest thing I've ever seen, or at least almost as dumb as my evil lambda...

Comment: @JonathanMee the signatures of most algorithms take their functors by value, at least according to cppreference.

Comment: @jaggedSpire It doesn't really matter that much how the standard algorithm accepts the argument, it's more about what it does with it internally. Which makes my code implementation defined (something I strive to avoid.)

Comment: @JonathanMee my point was more along the lines of it getting copied at least once due to the by-value parameter, and more times if it's implemented in terms of other algorithms

Comment: @jaggedSpire I can't figure out why the standard would be implemented like this. I've asked a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41108386/2642059