# I am trying to solve a question where i need array sum values but the code is not working I want to do something like this

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
Input:4
Input: 4 2 3 6
Output :29
```

Explanation:

- sort the array and then add 2+3=5 now we have 5 4 6
- Next we add 5+4=9 now we have 9 and 6
- next we add 9+6=15 and finally we return 29 as solution which is sum of 5+9+15=29

I have to write a code for the same.

Here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    vector<int> box;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        box.push_back(temp);
    }
    sort(box.begin(), box.end());
    vector<int> res;
    int sum = box[0];
    if (box.size() == 1)
    {
        cout << sum;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < box.size(); i++)
        {
            sum = sum + box[i];
            res[i] = sum;
        }
        res[0] = 0;
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
        {
            result += res[i];
        }
        cout << result;
    }
}
```

The code is not working properly and is running into errors can someone help..?
The question seems to be simple but I am unable to come up with and efficient solution for the same.

Comment: `vector<int> res(num);` res is empty when you call `[]`.

Comment: Not related to your question, but the dual combo of [`bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is a very bad idea. Matter of fact, better avoid both.

Comment: Please do not upload images of text, instead, copy the text itself here. Links can go bad, some employers block images at all and most important: if the image is of code we cannot copy the code to our own IDE. So please, copy the text of your problem statement instead of posting a picture of it. Also, please do elaborate on "not working properly". Add the error messages and line numbers at the very least, so we know what to look for.

Comment: this looks like a competitive problem/problem from some algorithm problem website. Can you post a link to the original source if that is the case? Otherwise can you share limits for the number of values being entered and their magnitude?

Answer (score 1):

Given the sorted `vector<int> box`, the value you're looking for could be assigned to `foo` like this:

```
foo += box[0] + box[1];
foo += box[0] + box[1] + box[2];
foo += box[0] + box[1] + box[2] + box[3];
```

It's pretty clear that for a given zero based element index `i` it will be added to `foo`, `size(box) - i` times (with the exception of the first element which will be added `size(box) - 1` times.) So you could very simply write the logic like this:

```
auto foo = box.front() * (size(box) - 1);

for(auto i = 1; i < size(box); ++i) {
    foo += box[i] * (size(box) - i);
}
```

This obviously expects that there will be at least 2 elements in `box` (and if `box` is empty this is even undefined.) So obviously this needs to be wrapped in an `if`-check. Anyway, if you trust in `accumulate` to [take your mutable lambda correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41108386/2642059) you can just directly return this sum like this:

```
accumulate(next(cbegin(box)), cend(box), box.front() * (size(box) - 1), [i = size(box)](const auto lhs, const auto rhs) mutable { return lhs + rhs * --i; })
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WpufF6)